# jquery autocomplete data source based on a dynamic input id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, autocomplete

I have one input form with autocomplete jquery search :

**HTML :**

```
<form class="pure-form" action="page.php" method="GET">
    <input name ='Jeu' id="search1">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _create: function() {
              this._super();
              this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
            },
            _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
              var that = this,
                currentCategory = "";
              $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                var li;
                if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                  ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                  currentCategory = item.category;
                }
                li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
                if ( item.category ) {
                  li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
                }
              });
            }
        });
    });         

    $(function() {
        var data1 = [ { label: "A1", category: "" },
            { label: "B1", category: "" } ];
        $( "#search1" ).catcomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: data1
        });
    });
```

Now I have a second data set :

```
    $(function() {
        var data2 = [ { label: "A2", category: "" },
            { label: "B2", category: "" } ];
        $( "#search2" ).catcomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: data2
        });
    });
```

Objective : Dynamically change input id from "search1" to "search2" in order to search into "data2" and not in "data1".

I managed to change the input id with jquery :

```
$('input[name=Jeu]').attr("id","search2");
```

**BUT** data1 is still used for the search, whereas input id has been changed to "search2" ! Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the id of an element is changed then it does not mean that all the events that are bound to that element will not be triggered anymore.

You have used the following code

```
$( "#search1" ).catcomplete({
     delay: 0,
     source: data1
});
```

It has bound the data1 with your search input. Now when you are changing the id, the binding still remains same.

I think the approach will be to change the binding first and then changing the id. That might work for you.

Try something like this.

```
function changeDataSet(){
  $( "#search1" ).catcomplete({
     delay: 0,
     source: data2
 });

 $('#search1').attr("id","search2");
}
```

and call this function from any button click or any other event.

Hope that helps.